# "Масса людей хочет [или хотят?] себя проявить"

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно: *масса людей **хочет** себя проявить* или *масса людей **хотят** себя проявить?*

По-русски вроде должно быть в единственном числе, не как по-английски, но всё-таки я сомневаюсь.

Comment: Aртем, здесь все написано. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo

Comment: Спасибо, Серж!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: масса людей хотят себя проявить.

Согласование во мн. числе (согласование по смыслу, а не по форме) подчеркивает количество производителей данного действия и их индивидуальность.

Comment: Спасибо, Sibylla!)

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта допустимы. Согласование во множественном числе подчеркивает количество и индивидуальность, а в единственном – единство этой "массы".

Comment: Спасибо! Хмм...

Answer (score 2):

> Как правильно?

Из  **[Розенталя:](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)**

> §184. **В единственном числе ставится сказуемое** при существительных
>   со значением неопределенного количества (***масса***, уйма, бездна,
>   пропасть и т. п.)...

То же у **Бельчикова** *("Практическая стилистика современного русского языка", М., 2012; стр. 246):*

> **Обратите внимание.** Если подлежащее — существительное со значением неопределённого
>   множества (*бездна, **масса**, пропасть, туча, уйма* и т. п. — все они
>   характерны для разговорной речи), то **глагол-сказуемое ставится в
>   единственном числе**…

Comment: Спасибо! Ну вот, все вы говорите разное.)))

Answer (score 0):

Вопреки строгим рекоммендациям ставить сказуемое в единственном числе при подлежащем типа "масса чего-либо/кого либо", я думаю, что есть случаи, когда мн. ч. уместней. Сравните: "Масса людей идет в одном направлении" и "Масса людей идут в разных направлениях". Ед. ч. вряд ли уместно во втором случае. Так и в предложении из вопроса. То ли толпа хочет себя проявить, то ли многие хотят себя проявить. Думаю, что вообще лучше не употреблять слово *масса* вместо *много* в подобных спорных случаях.

Comment: Спасибо! У Вас: *ед. ч. вряд ли уместно во втором случае.* Мне эта фраза режет слух. Хотя согласен: масса людей не может идти в разных направлениях. Именно потому, что "масса" здесь уже воспринимается единым целым. Я бы тогда сказал: *"Массы людей идут в разных направлениях".* Если же надо передать полную разнонаправленность и хаотичность, тогда  надо вообще сказать по-другому.